# How to use mutagen on a directory?

Tags: python, tagging, flac, mutagen

```
from mutagen.flac import FLAC
audio = FLAC("/file/path") 
audio["comment"] = "This is my comment"
audio.save()
```

I checked it tags the Flac file if I give file path. But how to run this on all files present in their respective album name folders? Like recursively?

I get `IsADirectory` error on giving a directory path.

I'm literally not a coder. It would be awesome if someone could help me in this. I have been searching for python cli program for the same but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I literally using common sense, copy pasting and trial and error wrote the answer to my own question.
More or less worked for me.

```
import os
from mutagen.flac import FLAC

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath("/path/of/directory/")):
    for file in files:
      if file.endswith(".flac"):
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
        audio = FLAC(os.path.join(root, file))
        audio["comment"] = "This is my comment"
        audio.save()
```